# Is it a good idea to use variadic templates to create a safer way to pass new objects

Tags: c++

Lets say I have a class that has a data member that is a pointer to an abstract class Foo. One of the class's setters, setFoo asks for pointer to one of Foo's subclasses. What the programmer is supposed to pass is a new object of the subclass like `setFoo(new FooBar(5, 10));` So that FooContainer is the only one holding a reference to the object and is the only one responsible for deleting that object. An example would be like...

```
class FooContainer final {
public:
    FooContainer() : currentFoo(nullptr) {}
    ~FooContainer() {
        delete currentFoo;
    }

    //Setter
    void setFoo(Foo *foo) {
        if (currentFoo != nullptr)
            delete currentFoo;

        currentFoo = foo;
    }

    //test that it holds the class
    void fireFoo() {
        currentFoo->func();
    }
private:
    Foo* currentFoo;
};
```

This has some big pitfalls like if I do these.

```
int main() {

    FooContainer fc1;
    holder.setFoo(nullptr);    //Error passing a null pointer
    holder.fireFoo();

    //---

    FooContainer fc2;

    Foo* fooBar = new FooBar(5, 10);
    holder.setFoo(fooBar);     //Error now two objects hold references to fooBar
    holder.fireFoo();

    delete fooBar;             //Error

    return 0;
}
```

The solution I came up with was to use a variadic template function to set foo where it's passed the foo subclass type and varargs to construct whatever the new Foo subclass is, like this.

```
    template <typename T, typename... Args>  
    void setFoo(Args... args) {
    currentFoo = new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
};
```

So now I can do `setFoo<FooBar>(5, 5);` which insures that currentFoo is not a null pointer and the FooContainer is the only reference holder. Is this be the correct way to go about this? I've never encountered a problem like this before, and If I'm getting something wrong I can always fall back to unique pointers.

Comment: You're basically trying to recreate a [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr). Use that instead.

Comment: I do not think it is a problem you need to worry about. You contract your functions as accepting a valid pointer, of which they take ownership from now on.

Comment: @0x499602D2, it will simply move OP's question to `unique_ptr` level. Original pointer still comes from somewhere, and there is nothing which guarantees it's validity - but a contract.

Comment: `if (currentFoo != nullptr)` should be `if (currentFoo != foo)`.

Comment: Btw, there is also a third problematic scenario there - one can pass a pointer to automatic variable.

Comment: @PeteBecker, better yet, separate setFoo with reset.

Comment: @SergeyA And that contract should be followed. The consequences of not doing so should not be the OPs concern. Or he can simply throw an exception when the contract is broken.

Comment: @0x499602D2, my point exactly. Ok, I got it - you were not answering to OP's question directly, you were basically advicing agains handmade unique_ptr. To this I have no objections, of course.

Answer (score 1):

For ownership, you should use one smart pointer

Then you may use setter (which allows easily to have polymorphic `Foo`):

```
class FooContainer final {
public:
    void setFoo(std::unique_ptr<Foo> foo) { // may be empty
        currentFoo = std::move(foo);
    }

    void fireFoo() {
        // may be empty if not set (constructor doesn't feed it) or set with nullptr
        if (currentFoo) {
            currentFoo->func();
        }
    }
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Foo> currentFoo;
};
```

or internal factory (which ensures that you always have value)

```
class FooContainer final {
public:
    template <typename...Ts>
    explicit FooContainer(Ts&&... args) {
        currentFoo = std::make_unique<Foo>(std::forward<Ts>(args));
    }

    template <typename...Ts>
    void createFoo(Ts&&... args) {
        currentFoo = std::make_unique<Foo>(std::forward<Ts>(args));
    }

    void fireFoo() {
        assert(currentFoo); // Cannot be nullptr (except after moved currently ;) )
        currentFoo->func();
    }
private:
    // You may even use `Foo currentFoo;` (which some changes above) if relevant
    // (think about copy/move)
    std::unique_ptr<Foo> currentFoo;
};
```